# How to get current BackLight setting in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, backlight

when my blackberry App starts, it wants to get the **current** Backlight timeout value which setted by user, for example, 30 seconds, 1 minutes.

I've found the Backlight class in API documents. But it only has *getTimeoutDefault()* method, which will always return 30 seconds.

Please tell me how to do. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think this is not possible. All you can take for granted is that the value will always be lower than 256 seconds.

Comment: thank u all the same. it seems blackberry has much to do on documentation and APIs. I got a alternative way to get user-setting backlight timeout: when the backlight gets dark, get the idle time of system. But it still can be wrong if there are other backlight control programms.